# ngRepeat multiple blank returns on Single Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to build a simple Pokedex in AngularJS using [Pokeapi](http://pokeapi.co/)

I just wanted to quickly get some data in a view, so used $http in my controller (don't worry, will be moved into a resource later) and than the ng-repeat directive to populate. I'm only calling 1 end point grabbing 1 object as a starting point. However, in doing so I'm getting multiple empty ng-repeat calls.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wfuller/8nqb0d0r/)

In the fiddle I'm returning 1 empty ng-repeat, then the object I requested, followed by 2 more blank ng-repeats.

In my actual application I'm getting the object I requested followed by 4 blank ng-repeats.

I've tried specifying the first array object with `$scope.characters = data[0];` but was undefined.

What am I missing to return the 1 object I specified?

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="pokedexCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="pokemon in characters">
        <div>Name: {{pokemon.name}}</div>
        <img ng-src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/{{pokemon.pkdx_id}}.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('pokedexCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    // get pokemon
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/89/'
  }).then(function successCallback(data) {
    $scope.characters = data;
    console.log($scope.characters);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {});
});
```

**Answer:**

Thanks to Grundy,

[JSFIDDLE ANSWER UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/wfuller/8nqb0d0r/1/)

For specific answer `$scope.characters = [data.data];` to return the single object.

Comment: this because ngRepeat can work and with array: iterate over element, and with object: iterate over object properties. Also you should use `data.data` because parameter to success function also contain information about request. And for solve your problem you can just wrap response to array: `$scope.characters = [data.data];`. Ofcourse this work if response is single element

Comment: @Grundy So if i'm understanding this correctly, using the `$scope.characters = data` I'm iterating over the other included properties "config:object, headers, & __proto__"? But, using data.data I'm getting the JSON Object than only requesting the Data Object (i.e. Object > Data {object})?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) can work and with array: iterate over element, and with object: iterate over object properties. In your case you iterate over response object passed to success calback.

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

for solving, first, you need use *data* property - this is real object that you expect.

So you can change your success callback like this

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.characters = response.data;
    ...
});
```

next, if you really want use ng-repeat in your case: wrap object to array, ofcourse if response.data already not an array

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {//
    $scope.characters = [response.data];
    ...
});
```

another way, if you know, that this response always return just one object - you not need in ng-repeat.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="pokedexCtrl">
    <div>
      <div>Name: {{pokemon.name}}</div>
      <img ng-src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/{{pokemon.pkdx_id}}.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and in callback

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.pokemon = response.data;
    ...
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the clarity in your response, I was originally thinking I was getting an Array of Arrays inside the Data Object populating the page. But this clears that up completely in knowing exactly what was happening. This was extremely helpful thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the API is returning an Object instead of an array with objects.

Convert the object into array and it will work as it should.

```
$scope.characters = [data];
```